# Calling a react hook again after a function is executed / inside a function (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks and I have created a react hook function which receives some data from an API and these data are shown on my page:

```
function useJobs () {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState({})
  const [departments, setDepartments] = React.useState({})
  const [tags, setTags] = React.useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchJSON('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(setJobs)
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
......
```

and here I have a delete function which is executed after a button is pressed and it deletes the items in my list.

```
function DeleteJob (jobid) {
  console.log('deletejob fired')
  console.log(jobid)
  axios({
    method: 'delete',
    url: '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid,
    headers: headers
  })
  useJobs()
}

.....

<IconButton aria-label='delete' style={{ color: 'red' }} variant='outlined' onClick={() => DeleteJob(job.id)}>
     <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```

but the problem is, that the item gets deleted but my display doesnt get updated; so in order to do that I called the `useJobs()` hook again in my function above so my display gets updated after the deletation; but I receive errors saying that Im breaking some react hook rules. how can I update my page  correctly?

Comment: You need to call a setter function (e.g. setJobs) from the hook declaration to update the state. The display won't get updated unless you update the state.

Comment: Why the downvote? oO

Answer (score -1):

Inside the deleteJob Function you should do the following:

```
    function DeleteJob (jobid) {
      console.log('deletejob fired')
      console.log(jobid)
      axios({
        method: 'delete',
        url: '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid,
        headers: headers
      }).then(job => {
    // I am assuming your '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid 
    //returns back the deleted job

    // since jobs is an array, you can filter the array and //update the state back with setJobs

    setJobs(jobs.filter(value => value.id != job.id));
            });
// If '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid 
    //does not returns back the deleted job use
setJobs(jobs.filter(value => value.id != jobid));
        }

    .....

    <IconButton aria-label='delete' style={{ color: 'red' }} variant='outlined' onClick={() => DeleteJob(job.id)}>
         <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton>
```

this should work fine

Comment: no '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid  doesnt return anything

Comment: then use jobId that was passed in the function